Pricing Treasury Futures Options on Bloomberg OVME screen

Hi all,
I am new to options pricing so just wanted to confirm the below -
If I would like to buy 14,020 contracts of the below and each contract contains 100,000 shares. According to OMON, the CSize is 100,000. I am assuming this is in shares.
The number of shares to be inputted in OVME is 14,020*100,000. Is this correct?
@AKdemy

I don't trade these options. But if the price is 109 and the face value is 100,000 that would suggest the number of "shares" in 1 contract is 1000, for a current market value of the underlying of 109,000. Then the option would be a 46,000 dollar item. Don;t press Buy or Sell until you check ;)

I am not too sure of face value but when I check OMON, it says Csize is 100,000. I am assuming that means each contract contains 100k shares?

I think @AKdemy (among others) would know the answer to this ...

I am surprised there have been no answers from more knowledgeable users. A Treasury futures contract has a face value of 100,000 usd (not 100,000 "shares"). The quoted price for the future is 109, which suggests a multiplier of 1000. The multiplier for the option is likely the same (in most cases I know) as the futures.

So in that case, I take the multiplier (i.e. 1000) multiplied by the number of contracts I would like to buy?

Why did you remove all of the relevant details of the question?

1 share is $100 face. The FVZ4 contract nominal is 100k, therefore that is 1k "shares". For 14,020 contracts you would buy 14,020,000 "shares".
The easy way to check this is - to put in 1 share, drop the strike to say $80. you will see that the intrinsic value is say 20 ticks or so

Thanks for this clarification. Makes a lot of sense :)

No probs. If its the answer ure after you should upvote it.
